# function overriding in javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

May be my question is wrong, actually in my MVC application I use to open a dialog window you can say using prototype/facebox, the issue is there is a function in the view opened in a dialog box and I wan to override that function on my parent view.

Any Help?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of dialog window is it? a css div? a new browser window as model popup? or an iframe?

in all three cases you can override the function:

for css div:

You are at browser level, so re-define the function directly:
say your old function is:

Now the new implementation:

```
myFunction = function(){
//// new implementation goes here!
}
```

For new browser window as model dialog or iframe:

```
window.parent.document.myFunction = function(){
/// your new implementation goes here
}
```